# Windows 10 closes all apps and folders in sleep/hybernation despite correct settings

Tags: windows-10, sleep, lenovo-laptop, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I've reinstalled windows last Sunday and everything went smooth. Fresh install from a Microsoft ISO onto a Lenovo Legion 5 laptop (Ryzen 7 RTX2060).

I'm using `Windows 10 Home` version `20H2`

What I expect to happen:
When closing the lid and not using the laptop for a few hours, I expect my apps and folders to be open from where I left.

What happens:
Everything is closed and the computer acts as if it was restarted.

**However, when I restart the laptop, it does open all the folders and apps. So this issue only arises when it goes to sleep or hibernation for longer than a certain amount of time.**

I am not sure, but I think that the issue arose after the Windows Update Client did an update on my system yesterday while it was sitting on my table with the lid closed

[image]

The options to reopen folders after a restart and open apps after a restart are both turned on.

**Update!**
I've discovered the same happens when I press the power button. The laptop is supposed to go to sleep, but instead it turns off completely and when I come back, everything is gone. I pressed it by accident just now and it all disappeared.

I've also set sleep and hibernate to 1 minute and 2 minutes to test if that is the problem and I can confirm that neither cause this issue. It seems quite random when it closes down completely and loses all apps.

Comment: It may be hybrid sleep doing this. Turn off hybrid sleep in Windows Advanced Power Properties and see if that helps.

Comment: When a machine goes into Hibernation, the machine is literally turned off and the kernel state is dumped, so there is no way a few hours would make a difference.  What is likely happening is your machine is actually going to sleep not hibernation.  KB2267602 wasn't a Windows Update so it couldn't be causing the behavior you describe.  Hybrid Sleep (powered on state) would explain your issues.  Please provide your power configuration as screenshots

Comment: John, Hybrid sleep is already turned off. I will try to turn it on and off to see if there was maybe a corruption in the setting.

Ramhound, thanks for clarifying, it goes to sleep after 30 minutes and hybernation after 180 minutes. What do you advice changing??  I don't remember it doing this before Monday evening.

I will try to install Lenovo Vantage, I remember using that on my previous install to manage power settings. My laptop also doesn't remember settings I make to the keyboard backlighting. Vantage may be needed for the laptop to function well?

Comment: I have Vantage installed on two laptops here. The newest version is fine and does not cause any issues.

Comment: I've tried everything, I notice that Windows also doesn't turn off Night Light when I open the computer in the morning. All of my programs and folders are also gone again when opening the laptop after closing the lid at the end of the day and then opening it again in the morning. So, despite having the correct settings, Windows closes everything and the night light stays on even though it's way past the time it should turn off.

Comment: I have now turned off hibernate to see if this makes a difference, so the laptop only goes to sleep after closing the lid and never to hibernate. Let's see.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar symptoms, and the cause was not that standby did not work, but that a device driver bugchecked during resume and there was no Blue Screen (BSOD) rendered (that was visible, anyway). There are three recommendations I have to help diagnose issues such as this. First, you need to replicate the problem, recording the time of sleep and time of resume. Then on you next boot:

1. From a command prompt, powercfg.exe has three options to explore: /SLEEPSTUDY, /SYSTEMSLEEPDIAGNOSTICS, and /SYSTEMPOWERREPORT. I suspect these all pull data from the system event logs, so avoid clearing them and/or stop automated tools/scripts from doing so.
2. You can explore the system event logs in the event viewer and evaluate what you see, event-wise, at the time of sleep and resume when it failed. This may be useful if #1 had no obvious red flags.
3. Use a tool like [WhoCrashed](https://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) or [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) which will show all dump files (BSOD or otherwise) found in your system. If there is a correlation between the time of a power state transition and one of these dumps, review the dump to see if you can recognize the driver involved and then research from there by updating, downgrading, or removing the driver and retesting.